# Having problems implementing bxSlider onto a webpage

Tags: jquery, css, slider, carousel

Is anyone else having problems implementing this http://bxslider.com/ slider onto a webpage because I am doing everything right as the instructions have said however the slider does not appear, simply 4 images one below the other appear on the page.

Here is how I have implemented mine:

Step 1: Link required files:

```
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
<link href="jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Step 2: Create HTML markup

```
<ul class="bxslider">
<li><img src="images/pic1.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/pic2.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/pic3.jpg" /></li>
<li><img src="images/pic4.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Step 3: Call the bxSlider

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
});
});
```

I seem to be calling the function fine and I think its somewhere in the CSS that its failing to show the slider. Not sure where though, would appreciate if someone can find out where i'm going wrong.

If you require me to post the full `CSS` file then please ask but I don't think its necessary.

Comment: You don't have to include both `[file].min.js` and `[file].js`. The `.min.js` will be fine.

Comment: where are the bxslider files placed? src="jquery.bxslider.min.js" ist this right? (download the examples and see where and how the files are included and in which folder they are)

Comment: @Pieter Thanks have just removed that

Comment: @caramba the files are as stated, `src="jquery.bxslider.min.js"` so they are in the relative folder to the `HTML` file

Comment: I've got this sorted people. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. Please close your question or, if there's a lesson to share, provide an answer below.

Comment: Ok, basically in this function `<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
});
});` I had a couple of invalid method calls which basically completely stopped the jQuery from working, I has like more then 30 so I cut it down to 5 or 6 important ones and got it working

Comment: Hi Ryman, could you answer your question and accept your answer, please?